# Handlebar/Express/Gulp Failed to lookup view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, handlebars.js

I used gulp to pipe separate javascript files and some .hbs files into this structure:

```
project
|-- app
|     |-- build
|        |--hbs-views
|            |--layouts
|                 |--layout.hbs
|            |--form.hbs
|        |--js
|            |--main.js
```

My view engine configuration uses express-handlebars:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../hbs_views/layouts'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.get('/', function list (req, res, next) {
       res.render('form');
});
```

And I receive this error when firing up the app:

`[Error: Failed to lookup view "form" in views directory "/hbs_views/layouts"]`

I'm assuming `main.js` is throwing this error, since it's the only javascript file, so I specified my path to `form.hbs` relative to the `main.js` file. I don't know why it can't find the file.